# I fell for a phishing attack. What should I do now?

Tags: passwords, phishing

Two weeks ago I visited a copy of the official website of www.runescape.com.

They asked me to fill in my account (in-game charc.) information; email (used for in-game name), password and Google authenticator linked to my game account.

Right after I filled all my information in I noticed that they asked something the real websites never would ask. That's when I realised I logged in to a fake version of the website.

I immediately change my email, password and my authenticator.
I didn't get a notification that they tried to steal my account through my email or authenticator.

Now I'm a bit worried that they know my IP address and can follow everything I do and look into my passwords saved on my internet browsers.
And that they can look into all my devices linked with my network.

What do you recommend I should do?

Comment: Every website you visit can know your IP address. The main risk from this would be if you had used the same password and email address for any other online accounts, not that they can spy on your devices.

Comment: You may want to verify that you used an up to date browser when you visited the site. If you didn't you may want to verify nothing was installed on your computer, e.g. by running an anti spyware tool. You visited an untrusted site, they may not have been *just* phishing. Fortunately most browsers auto-update nowadays.

Answer (score 7):

When you already changed the compromised password, then there is nothing left for you to do. Just remember that when you use the same password on a different service (you shouldn't do that; get a password manager) you must change that too.

If you want to be an extra good citizen, you might want to find out which company host the phishing site and report it so they can take it down (operating a phishing scam violates the terms of service of most webhosters). You would usually do that by checking the domain in a [whois-database](https://www.whois.com/whois/) and look for the "technical contact" information.

When it would be about a smaller and less well-known online game, you might also give a tip to the developers and the community so that they are aware of the phishing threat. But we are talking about Runescape here. They are in the online gaming business for longer than anyone else. Phishing should be old news for them.

> Now I'm a bit worried that they know my IP address and can follow everything I do and look into my passwords saved on my internet browsers. And that they can look into all my devices linked with my network.

That worry is very likely unjustified. There is not much you can do by knowing someone's IP address, and any of the other things you mentioned is very improbable unless you downloaded and ran some program from the website.